# Error while installing MVC Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I tried to install MVC Framework from the below URL

http://www.asp.net/mVC/

First it is installing web plateform installer 2.0, once it is done, it is throwing an error

Asp.net mvc2(visual studio 2008 tools) requires VS2008 Sp1

Please let me know what I have to install to run MVC

Below is my configration:

OS: Microsoft Windows Server 2003 [Enterprise edition, Service Pack 2]

VS: Visual Studio 2008

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even latest MSDN downloads and boxed versions of VS2008 comes without service pack installed. Have you tried to download and install the SP1? This should help: [VS2008 SP1 download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)